# Cache class method instance variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In this example code where I have child classes (`Bar`, `Baz`) inheriting the class methods of the parent (`Foo`), how might I ensure `@foo` is only created once across all children?

```
class Foo
  def self.foo
    # only want @foo to be set once across any child classes 
    # that may call this inherited method.
    @foo ||= expensive_operation
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def self.bar
    self.foo + 'bar'
  end
end

class Baz < Foo
  def self.baz
    self.foo + 'baz'
  end
end
```

Comment: **NB**: you are to mark the answer as correct if it helped you.

Comment: It does no harm, but `self.foo + 'bar'` can be written `foo + bar` as `self` is `Bar` when that is executed. Same for `Baz`.

Comment: This looks like an XY-question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of depending on a class-specific instance variable being present, just reference it directly:

```
class Baz < Foo
  def self.baz
    Foo.foo + 'baz'
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, ok. So I still need to set `@foo` in `self.foo`, but the callers need only call `Foo.foo`? And that will ensure `@foo` is only set once?

Comment: If you call `Foo.foo` then it's going to ensure that all calls are directed to exactly the same instance. If you call `self` they're on their own unless you start to share things between class instances, and then it gets messy. This is the most direct approach.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Just a tiny addendum: “all calls are directed to exactly the same instance” ⇒ namely, to the instance of class `Class`, named `Foo`.

Comment: @mudasobwa That's a more specific way of putting it which explains it a bit better.

Comment: I don't follow your and @mudasobwa's comments. Can you give a situation where the OP's code would result in the "expensive operation" being performed more than once, or where some other problem results?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The `@foo` variable is local to any given object, where `Foo` and `Baz` are not the same object.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what class instance variable is intended for - language mechanism to have one variable shared between classes which inherit from a class. It's generally not recommended to use because it behaves like you want to - and that's confusing for people coming from other languages.

```
class Foo
  def self.foo
    # notice @@
    @@foo ||= expensive_operation
  end

  def self.expensive_operation
    puts "Expensive operation"
    "cached value "
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def self.bar
    self.foo + 'bar'
  end
end

class Baz < Foo
  def self.baz
    self.foo + 'baz'
  end
end

Foo.foo
Bar.bar
Baz.baz
```

This prints `Expensive operation` only once.

Comment: Please **never** use class variables like that, there are many drawbacks.

Comment: @mudasobwa - what are the drawbacks?

Comment: E.g. try `@@foo = "WTF?"` immediately before `Foo.foo` after all the classes are defined.

Comment: I get `warning: class variable access from toplevel`. I'd expect that not to be possible, syntax error. I have no idea how it knows where @@foo is defined, but it's a warning that stops execution of program (nothing gets printed) so it's pretty close.

Comment: Warnings do not stop the execution of the program. “Nothing gets printed” because your code does not print anything. Use `puts` to print anything to `$stdout`.

Comment: I see puts works after, but not in `Foo.expensive_operation`. Confusing.

Comment: That is because `@@foo = "WTF?"` sets the `@@foo` variable on `Object`, which apparently shares the class variable with `Foo` and `expensive_operation` has never got called.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense.